# How to use COM in VBA for Word?

Tags: vba, com, ms-word, ms-office

I am working with VBA, in Microsoft Office 2007 and 2003 (Word specifically).

What I need is to use a custom [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) object from [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) and use its methods. I already do it in Word 2007 but it crashed in Word 2003.

This is the command that I am using:

```
    Dim oCOM as Object.

    Set oCOM = CreateObject("COMDLL.COMObj")
```

I got this error:

> File or assembly name COMDLL, or one of its dependencies, was not found.

How to make it work for Office 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was not create the COM object, It was an Office bug so I fixed it with a Microsoft update for Office 2003.

Here is the update URL:

[Update for Office 2003 (KB907417)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1B0BFB35-C252-43CC-8A2A-6A64D6AC4670&displaylang=en)

Comment: If you can use the COM object in VBscript but it bombs in VBA, then this is usually the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use [regsvr32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32) to register the COM component if you have just copied the file to the Word 2003 machine.

E.g.:

```
    regsvr32 yourcomfilesname.dll
```

Comment: Well I register it with RegAsm.exe and it works fine with Word 2007, even I did it for Power Point 2003 and 2007 and in all these cases it works perfectly but with Word 2003 it didn't work.